# Exporting database from MySql Workbench

Tags: database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have made a database in MySql Workbench. Along the design, I deleted a couple of tables since they weren't necessary.
   But, when I try to export the database to phpmyadmin, all of those tables appear in the code.
   How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you commited your tables deletion?

Comment: No, i'm new to mysql workbench. how do i do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did you do to "make" the database?

Comment: Using MySql Workbench i added tables, making the links between them: one to one, one to many, many to many.Then some new rules appeared and a few tables weren't needed. So i right clicked on them and deleted them. But when i tried to export the database in sql format, those tables still appeared, meaning they weren't completely deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE.

I think it is very easy.

Suppose first you add a table in the database. for doing that.

1. Click on Database Menu. and then click on "Next to Database".
2. You all database will show on left side.
3. Click on db and then right click on table. Create New Table.
4. Now you will create a new table. Click on Apply and you watch table is created.

Now You need to drop this table.

Just right click on a table. and click on drop table. and a dialog box will open. Choose drop and the your created table will be deleted.

Now if you export your db, this deleted table will not show up.

If you had made relationships among different tables then the table will not be deleted until you remove that relationship.

Thanks.